# What is needed to get pdflatex to output CMYK colors?

Tags: color

I thought that if I loaded xcolor with the cmyk option, and specified my custom colors with the cmyk space, I would get a PDF which would be all-CMYK.

But Acrobat Preflight is reporting that it's all RGB.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk,svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkGold}{cmyk}{0,0.2139,0.7807,0.2667} 
\usepackage{opensans}
\begin{document}
This is in \textcolor{DarkGold}{dark gold}
\end{document}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/q/6241282/5011478.

Comment: I've just checked an uncompressed PDF (`\pdfcompresslevel=0`) and I get `0 0.2139 0.7807 0.2667 k 0 0.2139 0.7807 0.2667 K` in the PDF: that's a CMKY colour. As in the question @gusbrs links to, this looks like misidentification by the other PDF tools.

Comment: on my pc preflight says that it is ok, I also tried `\selectcolormodel{rgb} \color{red!20!blue!17!green}{BLA}` and then preflight complained. (The pdf were compiled with a pdflatex from a current texlive).